# filter python output that has list of integers

Tags: python, csv, pycharm

I've imported a csv file to PyCharm and trying to print a specific list from the rows and so far successful. I have the output as list of integers. I'm trying to filter the list and print only integers greater than a specific number(500 in this case) but have no idea how and where to use "if" condition.

Here's my code:

```
import csv

f = open('C:\Python36-32\movies.csv', encoding='utf')

csv_f = csv.reader(f)
next(csv_f, None)

for row in csv_f:
    content = row[3]

print(content)

f.close()
```

And here's the output:

```
489
472
615
784
251
365
956
902
397
668
...
```

output continues.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: `print [x for x in content if x > 500]`

Comment: This code should not work, the print is misaligned and it should print only the last line.

Comment: It looks like your indentation may be off. Anyway, you can just add an if statement before the print statement

Comment: `newList = filter(lambda x: x > 500, content)`

Comment: I think you'll need to cast `row[3]` to `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
import csv

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    next(reader, None)      # skip the headers

    for row in reader:
        if int(row[3]) > 500:
            print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks @sparkandshine. It worked! I just got to do a couple of changes to code to ignore header. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

f = open('C:\Python36-32\movies.csv', encoding='utf')

csv_f = csv.reader(f)
next(csv_f, None)

for row in csv_f:
    content = row[3]
    if content>500:
        print(content)

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your if statement inside your for loop, and also move your print statement into the loop.

Amended loop:

```
for row in csv_f:
    content = row[3]
    if content > 500:
        print(content)
```

As an aside I would also recommend using the 'with' context manager for file operations, rather than manually closing them. i.e.

```
with open('C:\Python36-32\movies.csv', encoding='utf', 'r') as f:
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    next(csv_f, None)
```